# Spring boot test using @Sql scripts keep fails after last test method execution

Tags: sql, spring, testing, junit

I test this code

```
@SpringBootTest
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
@Sql(scripts = {"/sql/create-member.sql"})
@Transactional
class MemberServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private MemberRepository memberRepository;

    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(longs = 1L)
    public void SelectMemberTest_A(Long id) {

        Member member = memberRepository.findById(id).get();

        assertEquals(1L, member.getId());
    }

    @ParameterizedTest
    @ValueSource(longs = 2L)
    public void SelectMemberTest_B(Long id) {

        Member member = memberRepository.findById(id).get();

        assertEquals(2L, member.getId());
    }
}
```

create-member.sql

```sql
CREATE TABLE Member
(
    id       int auto_increment
        primary key,
    username varchar(45),
    phone    varchar(45),
    address  varchar(45),
);

INSERT INTO Member (username, phone, address)
VALUES ('John', '111-1111-1111', null);
INSERT INTO Member (username, phone, address)
VALUES ('Jane', '111-1111-1111', null);
INSERT INTO Member (username, phone, address)
VALUES ('emily', '111-1111-1111', null);
INSERT INTO Member (username, phone, address)
VALUES ('chris', '111-1111-1111', null);
INSERT INTO Member (username, phone, address)
VALUES ('peter', '111-1111-1111', null);
INSERT INTO Member (username, phone, address)
VALUES ('sarah', '111-1111-1111', null);
INSERT INTO Member (username, phone, address)
VALUES ('kate', '111-1111-1111', null);
```

I keep fail the last test method which is `SelectMemberTest_B(Long id)` with exception `Table "MEMBER" already exists; SQL statement: ...`

I know if I put `@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CALSS)` annotation on top of class, test Data would be created once and all test methods would share data.

But the last test still keep fail.

[test result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJxvG.png)

Answer (score 0):

`@Sql` declared at a class level is run for each test method (default setting is to be run before method execution). You should add another `@Sql` script that drops the table and specify it to run after method:

```
@Sql(scripts = "cleanup.sql", executionPhase = AFTER_TEST_METHOD)
```